# repackage Excel file price catalog worksheet for distribution as a PDF

Tags: excel, pdf

I have an Excel file that has several tables of data with long conditional formulas that combine to ultimately generate a quote for our customers.  Our product line has infinite product permutations.  Presently, we distribute an Excel file internally that allows employees to select specs from drop down lists, fill in and/or select some other factors that define the part.  The sheet then calculates pricing and populates a form for printing/emailing/faxing.  The data/calculations in the Excel file show actual costs and markup, so the file can not be sent to customers.

I have an idea that could populate one table with all the data necessary to generate the quote.  The table would have cost and markup combined, so the customers could see the table (although I would like to keep it hidden).  I wanted to distribute a PDF with the data securely hidden, drop down selectors, text and check boxes that would allow a customer to have a price sheet.  Can a PDF file do this?  If so, what language/tools should I use/consider??  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A PDF file would be a great way to do this,  I recommend getting cutepdf and setting the print area inside your spreadsheet to just the stuff you want the end user to see.  Then print with the cutepdf virtual printer and send that to your customer.

In my experience, cutepdf generates more reliable results than the official adobe pdf printer/converter.

Comment: Maybe I am making this harder than it is.  I have a functioning form in Excel now that pulls values as previously described.  Are you saying, I can just take cutepdf, export the sheet as a PDF form and it will continue to function as it did in Excel?